# Request asyncronous execution on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I've build AWS SAM template with all resources required to run my Lambda function, however, I'm not 100% sure how I can make calls to run the functions asyncronously. I have tried making requests to my endpoint with the InvokeType header equal to Event, however, this didn't work. Do I need to provide additional configuration to my .yaml file?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  my-sls-app

  Sample SAM Template for my-sls-app

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 900 

Resources:
  fetchContactsLim:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: functions/fetch_contacts_lim
      FunctionName: fetchContactsLim
      Description: SAM Demo get EC2 regions
      Role: arn:aws:iam::725516397874:role/all_functions
      Handler: main.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        fetchContactsLimAPI:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /fetch-limited
            Method: post

Outputs:
  fetchContactsLimAPI:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/fetch-limited/"

    fetch-contacts-lim:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt fetch-contacts-lim.Arn
```

Comment: `I have tried making requests to my endpoint with the InvokeType header equal to Event, however, this didn't work` --- How do you know this?

Comment: @AADProgramming, it would wait for the app to return the data instead of returning the empty body, which happens with AWS lambda when your request gets processed asyncronously. Any ideas if I am missing something here?

Comment: There are two kinds of async lambdas - one which is simply an async function which will return data and the other with Event invoke type which is meant to just run and return immediately without data. It's unclear which you are trying to do - for the latter type, if you need the results you will have to do something such as store in database and fetch etc...